# Dropping a row from a dataframe using multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Should be a simple question but having difficulty. I have a dataset that I want to basically keep all rows except when these two conditions are met.

I am trying to use filter but this is not the desired outcome. Instead I want to just drop the row when conditions are met, not use the double negative.

```
df %>% filter(Sites != "X" & Date != "09/13/2022")
```

Preferred solution:

```
df %>% dropfunction(Sites == "X" & Date == "09/13/2022")
```

Comment: By De Morgan's Laws, you can use a single negation: !X & !Y == !(X | Y).  I'd stick with `filter` though

Comment: ```df %>% filter(!(Sites == "X" & Date == "09/13/2022"))```